# How to retrieve image name from url in javascript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In my case, it's not straight forward like `SomeDomain/test.com/car.jpeg`
but instead it's a token based image like:

```
SomeDomain/upload/document/ciOiJIUzUxMiJ9.eyJmaWxlX2lkiZXhwIjoxNjEwNjQ4MDY2fQ.e4doztYLOl6FTafUc7bJXrzwb-4FgaXTkJkk8S9GC4gsZhMVRh?subscription-key=f2721f4fa0a2f
```

I can retrieve this in a browser. I can even see the name of the image on the browser tab.

Comment: I'm guessing that maps to the image - to get the name you'll probably need to make a little ajax call to that endpoint, and take a peek at the data that comes back - I'm pretty sure you're not going to be able to get any useful into from just that URL string on it's own.

Comment: In that example, which is image name?

Comment: Thanks @Kyle, yes i found the same solution and implemented. Its working now.

Comment: @O.o That's not mentioned explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to get the actual url, just use this:

```
let url = window.location.href; 
/* 
>> "http://somedomain/upload/document/ciOiJIUzUxMiJ9.eyJmaWxlX2lkiZXhwIjoxNjEwNjQ4MDY2fQ.e4doztYLOl6FTafUc7bJXrzwb-4FgaXTkJkk8S9GC4gsZhMVRh?subscription-key=f2721f4fa0a2f"
*/
```

If you are trying to get the path, use this:

```
let path = window.location.pathname; 
/*
>> "/upload/document/ciOiJIUzUxMiJ9.eyJmaWxlX2lkiZXhwIjoxNjEwNjQ4MDY2fQ.e4doztYLOl6FTafUc7bJXrzwb-4FgaXTkJkk8S9GC4gsZhMVRh"
*/
```

And if you want to get the name after the last slash, use this:

```
let path = window.location.pathname;
let nameAfterLastSlash = path.substring(path.lastIndexOf('/'), path.length);
/*
>> "/ciOiJIUzUxMiJ9.eyJmaWxlX2lkiZXhwIjoxNjEwNjQ4MDY2fQ.e4doztYLOl6FTafUc7bJXrzwb-4FgaXTkJkk8S9GC4gsZhMVRh"
/*
```

Comment: no @e2017 that's not how it's in my case. I have mentioned that in my description.

Answer (score 0):

I just got this solution and its working. And also as suggested by @kyle

```
getFileName(filePath) {
    let fileName = null;
    const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open("GET", filePath, false);
    xhr.send();
    if (xhr.status==200) {
      const contentDisposition = xhr.getResponseHeader('Content-Disposition');
      fileName = contentDisposition.split(';')[1].split('filename')[1].split('=')[1].split('.')[0].trim();
    }
    return fileName;
  }
```